# How to deal with minor factual inaccuracy in questions?

Tags: discussion, editing, etiquette

This question [What happens to Mr 3?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/5866/99) contains a minor factual inaccuracy (Mr. 3's ability is wax, not clay). It doesn't affect the core of the question though. The [answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/5867/99) points it out, and then answers the core question.

From an etiquette perspective, I have two questions:

- Is it better to edit the question to remove the inaccuracy, rather than pointing it out in the answer?
- What should a third user do in this case? Edit both the question and answer, or just leave it as it is?

**Note:** I use this question and answer only as an example to illustrate the point. Not nitpicking either of the users.

Comment: You can always leave a comment, and let the OP correct it. Or even if he doesn't correct it, at least people can see your comment with the correct info.

Answer (score 5):

The question should remain intact. Remember that it was the OP's intention, and others may have the same misconception and same inaccuracy.

Pointing it out in the answer also gives valuable info even for those who didn't ask for it.